# Simple Javascript Object and "this"

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object

Quick question. Why does the following give a `this.testFunction is not a function` error?

```
Test = {
    data: true,

    testFunction: function() {
        this.data = true;
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.data = false;
        this.testFunction();
        console.log(this.data);
    }
};

$(document).ready(Test.initialize);
```

Comment: Make sure you are calling the method as a `function` and not a `reference`; something like: `$(document).ready(Test.initialize());`

Comment: `$(document).ready($.proxy(Test, "initialize"))`

Comment: @faino — That would call the function *immediately* and pass its return value to `ready()`, which is not the desired effect.

Comment: @Quentin check [this out](http://jsfiddle.net/CpZYf/), showing it reacts as expected. Resetting the `data` variable is pointless as the method being called in question resets the variable either way.

Comment: @faino That may be so, but it's clearly not what he intends, which is for the function to be called on ready, not immediately.

Comment: @faino: Your jsFiddle is calling the function inside a `window.onload` handler, and passing `undefined` to `$(document).ready()`. Doesn't make any sense to do that.

Comment: You're probably right, I was answering in the prospect of an initial call to set an `Object` or `variable` as is. It doesn't make sense to run the script in such a way; however the OP was curious as to why the call failed and I offered a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't calling `Test.initialize`, you are passing its *value*. This separates it from it's context, so when it is called, `this` is not `Test`.

The usual way around this is to use an anonymous function expression:

```
$(document).ready(function () { Test.initialize() });
```

You can also use (with more limited browser support) [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
$(document).ready(Test.initialize.bind(Test));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this context this is set to the global object which does not have the function testFunction().  For a detailed explanation of the this keyword see this answer: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's designers have been a bit naughty on the rules behind the this keyword. `this` takes the values of the left-handside of a MemberExpression, i.e:

```
var a = {
  b: function () {
    // this = a
  }
};

a.b();
```

This creates problem when you do something like:

```
var universe = {
  answer: 42,
  getTheAnswer: function () {
    return this.answer;
  }
}

var foobar = universe.getTheAnswer;

foobar();
```

In this case `this` in the function `getTheAnswer` won't be bind to the `universe` object but to the global object, which is evil. What you can do to solve this issue is use the `bind` function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), i.e:

```
var foobar = universe.getTheAnswer.bind(universe);

foobar(); // => 42
```

So in your case, you can simply do:

```
$(document).ready(Test.initialize.bind(Test));
```

Hope it helped!